# Vuetify vertically center autocomplete in app bar?

Tags: javascript, css, vuetify.js

If I add an `v-autocomplete` in `v-app-bar` it appears at the top of the app bar, everything else in there is centered.

```js
    <v-app-bar app color="primary" dark>
      <v-icon class="mr-3">mdi-chart-line</v-icon>
      <v-toolbar-title>Centered title</v-toolbar-title>
      <v-autocomplete
        filled
      ></v-autocomplete>
      <v-spacer />
      <v-btn to="/products" nuxt text>
        Centered button
      </v-btn>
    </v-app-bar>
```

Is there some option I'm missing? Or some other element I should be wrapping around the autocomplete? I'm trying to add as little custom CSS as possible so I can easily update later.

It looks like this:

[image: app bar input at top]

Comment: Can you provide a link to the running application?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because of *details* provided by this component. such as error message or hints. So if you want these features you can increase `height` of app bar with `height` property.

and if you don't need them you can add `hide-details` to `v-autocomplete`.
This will put component fit to app bar and if you want smaller input you can add `dense` to it. to become smaller or increase `height` of app bar.

So final code is:

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-app-bar app color="primary" dark>
      <v-icon class="mr-3">mdi-chart-line</v-icon>
      <v-toolbar-title>Centered title</v-toolbar-title>
      <v-autocomplete
        filled dense hide-details
      ></v-autocomplete>
      <v-spacer />
      <v-btn to="/products" nuxt text>
        Centered button
      </v-btn>
    </v-app-bar>
  </v-app>
</div>
```